# jsTree removes div when the page is loaded

Tags: jstree

The jsTree [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/G789k/376/) has a div next to it (id=div2), however when the page is displayed the div is not there. If you check the DOM (with Inspect Element) the div element disappeared. What's wrong with this code?

The HTML:

```
<div id="treediv" />
<div id="div2" style="width:30px;height:30px;background-color:orange" />
```

The Javascript:

```
var tree = [
    { "data" : "Node1"  },
    { "data" : "Node2"  },
    { "data" : "Node3" },
    { "data" : "Node4" },
    { "data" : "Node5" }
];
$("#treediv").jstree({
    "json_data" : { "data" : tree },
    "plugins" : [ "json_data", "ui"]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is wrong, `<DIV />` is not valid, should be `<DIV></DIV>`

For example:

```
<div id="treediv"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width:30px;height:30px;background-color:orange" ></div>
```